# How to do SMC reset when keyboard is not working?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, battery

My left shift, option and control keys don't work from the last 1 year. I have got used to using the right shift and option keys. Now I need to do a SMC reset for various reasons and Apple Docs say that for my model I need to:

> "Using the built-in keyboard, press Shift-Control-Option on the left
>   side of the keyboard, then press the power button at the same time."

*Model: Macbook 8,1 (Early 2011, 13" Macbook Pro)*

**Question**: If I remove the back case, unplug the battery and then press the power button for 5sec, will this reset the SMC? As per the documents this method is for notebooks with removable battery.If not then what are my options to reset the SMC without replacing the keyboard?

PS: USB/Bluetooth Keyboards cannot reset the SMC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in these models you technically don't need to press the power button for 5 seconds, although there's no reason not to.

Assuming you have the correct tools you can remove the bottom case, disconnect the battery for a while, reconnect it and the SMC should be reset (assuming there's no other underlying problems such as a logic board fault).

Hope this helps.